# Rails with Devise - Use current_user after 'remote => true' submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise, warden

I have a three part user signup that work with two separate models: User, and Customer Info.  There's a user signup that I submit remotely, and it goes to the next part of the form.  I want to be able to use the `current_user` variable when I submit the Customer Info row.  The following code works when I test without remote, but it just doesn't even create the row at all when I do it with the remote.  Is there another variable I can use in lieu of this variable?  Or is there a better way of accomplishing this?

```
  def create
    @customer_info = CustomerInfo.new(params[:customer_info].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer_info.save
        format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: 'Customer info was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: tasks_url, status: :created, location: @customer_info }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @customer_info.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Assuming CustomerInfo `belongs_to` User, then it should have a `user_id` attribute, and your merge should work.  Are you sure it's getting called, AND that `current_user.id` is the right value?  Add a line like `logger.debug "current_user is #{current_user.inspect}"` to the beginning of the create method, then look in `development.log` to see what you get.  I wonder if the create method is even getting called ... perhaps you need to specify the method as POST or something?

Comment: Have you added `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` to your layout? Because if you do not have that then your user will probably be logged out when you use `remote: true` because of RequestForgeryProtection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a devise config situation.  I wasn't allowing users to be unconfirmed for any amount of time, so "curent_user" was staying empty even after they signed up.  I added `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days` and restarted the server and that worked.